# What is an effective preservative for guar gum slime?

Tags: home-experiment

I am attempting to find an effective preservative for guar gum slime. I am using typical recipes:

A borax solution of 4%, a guar gum solution of 5% using distilled water, and a mix ratio of 20:1 (guar to borax). I am trying to find a preservative I can add to this homemade method to overcome guar gums' short shelf life.

I am going to try to use propylene glycol in the mixing of the guar solution next time. It's cited as a good way to disperse the guar powder to avoid clumping, but is also listed as a preservative on one of the many Mattel slime variants found on the patent, *Guar Gum Based Flowing Gel Play Composition<sup>[[1]](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/3e/8d/0a/557830d8346cbd/US6387169.pdf)</sup>*.

There are also some preservatives cited that are used as cosmetic preservatives but not having any knowledge of chemistry I don't know where to start trying those out in my recipes.

Primary questions:

1. What would be a good preservative for guar gum slime?
2. How and at what point in the process would I add the preservative?

The traditional web searches yield nothing but endless recipes for quickly expiring guar gum slime.

**Reference:**

[[1]](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/3e/8d/0a/557830d8346cbd/US6387169.pdf): Cordova, A. Guar Gum Based Flowing Gel Play Composition. 6387169, May 14, 2002.

Comment: When you say preservative, do you picture an antimicrobial agent or something to slow a purely chemical breakdown of the slime?